# jQuery math and split to return only requested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, split, element

how do I achieve this grid using jQuery and adding that background using .css() method ?

I have tried using `eq()` or `index()` or `filtering()` but I am not able to return only elements that I need from grid.

I need to return only corner elements and for middle I need to return each element to treat separately.

[image]

**[fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/SK48T/310/)**

Comment: You need to iterate cells and check if loop index is equal to index of specific cell, add your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over all cells and use `if` statement to check what background should be appended to that cell. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6j8v6q3/3/).

```
/*
  Here are some global variables
  c - Array of rows in the table
  x - Temporary x-coordinate used in loop (left is 0, right is c.length - 1)
  y - Temporary y-coordinate used in loop (top is 0, bottom is c.length - 1)
  c1 - Distance from x-axis translated to center of the table
  c2 - Distance from y-axis translated to center of the table
  cols - An array of RGB colors
*/
var c = $('.row'), x, y, c1, c2,
  cols = [
    135, 203, 205,
    235, 164, 158,
    197, 191, 88,
    214, 117, 165
  ];

// Iterate over all cells
for(y = 0; y < c.length; y++) for(x = 0; x < c.length; x++){
  // Calculate x-distance and y-distance from the center
  c1 = Math.abs(x - 2.5);
  c2 = Math.abs(y - 2.5);

  // If we are in the corner, color it in one way
  if(c1 > 1 && c2 > 1) x < 3 ? setBg(x, y, 166, 233, 197) : setBg(x, y, 168, 156, 197);
  // Otherwise use `cols` variable
  else if(c1 < 1 && c2 < 1) setBg(x, y, cols.shift(), cols.shift(), cols.shift());
}

// This function set background to cell at (x, y) from RGB value
function setBg(x, y, r, g, b){
  c[y].children[x].style.background = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
}
```

Comment: WOW this is quite awesome

Comment: @mcmwhfy. If you found my answer useful, consider accepting it.

Comment: yes of course, one last request if if you want to add a proper description of your code in order to help other people to understand your methods. Thank you !

Comment: @mcmwhfy. Even a begginer Javascript programmer can easily understand my code, but anyway, I added a description.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an example of how the first corner was coloured. By changing the indexes of the loops, you are able to colour the other corners.

```
for (var i = 0; i < c.length - 4; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < c.length - 4; j++) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Try and think about how to access the 4 middle cells and give each of them their own colour.

You can take a look at the jsfiddle with four coloured corners here: https://jsfiddle.net/wzztoch8/.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally create a function to help here ->
eg.

```
function fill(x1,y1,x2,y2,color) {
  $('.row:nth-child(n+'+y1+'):nth-child(-n+'+y2+
    ') span:nth-child(n+'+x1+
    '):nth-child(-n+'+x2+')')
    .css({"background-color":color})
}

fill(0,0,2,2,'#00ffcc');
fill(0,5,2,6,'yellow');
```